# Объясните как тут работает проверка на целое и то что введенное значение не символы? Заранее спасибо

Tags: c

```
int main() {
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "RUS");
    int a, b, c;
    char s1, s2, s3;
    float d;
    printf("Введите значение переменной а=");
    if (scanf("%d%c", &a, &s1) != 2 || s1 != '\n') {
        printf("Некорректно введено значения а. Введите целое значение а!");
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Тут же нет такой проверки.

Comment: @user7860670, ну вообще-то есть.

Answer (score 0):

## Что реализовано:

- Считываем число ещё один символ за ним.
- ысфта возвращает количество успешно считанных переменных. Мы просили две, значит если считались обе, то вернётся 2.
- При считывании числа scanf остановится как только прочитает все цифры (после необязательного знака). Если числа вообще нет, он вернёт 0.
- Если удалось считать оба значения, то в s1 лежит следующий за целым числом символ. Делается проверка, что он является переносом строки, т. е. после числа не было никакого мусора до конца строки.

## Нюансы:

- Код, который позволит подготовить возможность сделать вторую попытку ввода не реализован.
- Пробельные символы после числа тоже будут расцениваться как неверный ввод.
- Если при вводе числа пользователем происходит переполнение int'а, мы об этом никогда не узнаем.

## Баги:

- Если используется перенаправление ввода и сразу за числом последует конец файла, всё пойдёт не по плану: ввод будет рассматриваться как неверный. И я не помню, что вернёт scanf - 1 или EOF. Подозреваю, что EOF.